# Will Code Signing Certificate help to reduce risk of running JAVA applet with DLL library included?

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

I have created a Java applet which uses DLL file included in JSSC library for communication with COM port.

When I run the applet I get security warning saying that application will run with unrestricted access and that information is unreliable or unknown source. Exactly it says:
This application will run with unrestricted access which may put your computer and personal information at risk. The information provided is unreliable or unknown so it is recommended not to run this application unless you are familiar with its source.

And to run I have to click that I accept the risk. This confirming is tiring especially if the applet is run approximately once at 2 min.

I wonder if it is possible to get rid of this confirm dialog by signing this applet with Code Signing Certificate from reliable source.

Comment: seeing as more and more browsers discontinue support for applets, creating new ones might not be a good idea.

Comment: From the doc here: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml the message you seems to be the one displayed for the lowest security risk. Can't you just check the 'Do not show this again' checkbox?

Comment: There is no "Do not show this again" checkbox. Only I accept th risk...

Comment: Maybe if I bought the certificate there would be the checkbox Do not show this again...

Comment: You can test your hypothesis by creating a homemade self-signed certificate and signing the applet following the Oracle instructions. On the test machine (which may be a VM), install the self-signed certificate into the browser as a trusted certificate. The method varies by browser/platform, but there are instructions available for all of them online.